# Tuning the performance of reading a large InputStream in java

Tags: java

I want to **read a large InputStream** and return it as a String.
This InputStream is a large one. So, normally it takes much time and a lot of memory while it is excuting. 
The following code is the one that I've developed so far.
I need to convert this code as it does the job in a lesser time consuming lesser memory.

Can you give me any idea to do this.

```
BufferedReader br =
    new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(
            connection.getInputStream(),
            "UTF-8")
        );

StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder(1000);

char[] buffer = new char[4096];

int n = 0;
while(n >= 0){
    n = br.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
    if(n > 0){
        response.append(buffer, 0, n);
    }
}
return response.toString();
```

Thank you!

Comment: what is a "lot" of memory. It's inevitable that you are going to need enough memory to hold the entire String you're building. Are you seeing something dramatically worse than you'd expect?

Comment: Yes. it is true that the consumed memory is proportional to the size of the response(String). But here, it is about to use the memory effectively(Reducing the unnecessary memory usage, etc). For an example here I have used the StringBuilder instead of appending the input to a same String using +'s (like str = str + newStr)) to reduce the unnecessary memory usage. Like that, I expected about further ideas to make my code much better by managing the memory and speedup the code.

Comment: I'm reading a binarry data array that is coming from the created connection as a response to a set of parameters passed using a URL as follows : URL url = new URL(sendURL);
 HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

Comment: 'I want to read a large InputStream and return it as a String.'. You probably don't really want to do that at all. If the String is large you are risking running out of memory, and if it is reasonably small you are still adding latency. You should consider reorganizing the caller of this method so that it can use a Reader or an InputStream.

Comment: What do you mean by "You should consider reorganizing the caller of this method"? What is the meaning of "recognizing"? I didn't get it.

Comment: Reorganizing. Not recognizing. I am using the word in its normal sense.

Comment: @EJP - Precisely, I imagine Java doesn't provide something like InputStream.readAll() for exactly this reason. Though you'd probably find this in Apache commmons IO if you really needed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are doing buffered I/O you can just read one char at a time from the buffered reader.  Then build up the string, and do a toString() at the end.

Comment: Isn't this reading chars, while storing them to a char array is better than the reading each char and buildUp the string? I mean read() Vs read(char[], int start, int end)

Comment: That is what the buffered reader does under the covers....  Try looking at the source of BufferedReader.

Answer (score 1):

You may find that for large files on some operating systems, `mmap`ing the file via [FileChannel.map](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#map%28java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode,%20long,%20long%29) will give you better performance - map the file and then create a string out of the mapped ByteBuffer.  You'll have to benchmark though, as it may be that 'traditional' IO is faster in some cases.

Comment: Yep. I'm new to this FileChannel.map. Can this be used with the OP that reads a URL

Comment: @dogbane and Namalak: To be fair that was not made clear until after I left my answer :)  I'll leave this here in case someone comes along later and wants to do the same for a File.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know in advance the likely maxiumum length of your string? You currently specify an intiial capacity of 1000 for your buffer. If what you read is lots bigger than thet you'll pay some cost in allocating larger internal buffers.

If you have control over the life-cycle of what you're reading, perhaps you could allocate a single re-usable byte array as the buffer. Hence avoiding garbage collection.

Answer (score 0):

Increase the size of your buffer. The bigger the buffer, the faster all the data can be read. If you know (or can work out) how many bytes are available in the stream, you could even allocate a buffer of the same size up-front.

Comment: Thanks. 1000 is good up to now. Unnecessarily increasing of the buffer size is also inefficient isn't it?

Comment: I meant the char buffer which you have set to 4096.

Answer (score 0):

You could run the code in a separate thread... it won't run any faster but at least your program will be able to do some other work instead of waiting for data from the stream.